# C# Winforms how to resize image and save

Tags: image

hi I want to open a image file with openfiledialog and resize to upload to database so please help me with this code which I got from some where but I don't know how to make it working thanks

```
private void ResizeImg(double scaleFactor, Stream sourcePath, string tragetPath)
{
    using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourcePath))
    {

        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * scaleFactor);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * scaleFactor);
        var resizingImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        var resizeGraph = Graphics.FromImage(resizingImg);
        resizeGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        resizeGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        resizeGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        resizeGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
        resizingImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying source and target rectangle, it doesn't stretch.

Change

```
 resizeGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
```

to

```
 var srcRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
 resizeGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle,srcRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

BTW: Consider ImageFormat.Jpeg or .Png for Save, because you cannot write all image formats you can read.

Comment: thanks for your reply and correction so now kindly tell me how can i call this function by pressing button of upload and openfile dialog  kindly give me complete code because i have try alot but still i couldn't do that